# Why image showing black

Tags: texturing

Why image showing black. As the image and the nodes looks fine to me.

[image]

I have my transparent png image. When i unwrap and added texture. Image and the background look black.

[image]

May i know the reason why the texture and its background getting black.

**I need this way the result**

[image]

But its fake or wrong method i just put a plane on top it like this

[image]

and got the above result. But i want a clean way result.

Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the alpha as a factor for the background colour, otherwise you end up with transparent material.

Also I suggest using material viewport instead of texture viewport

[image]